# How to creating WCF service for communicating Xamarin.forms with Sqlserver

Tags: sql, wcf, xamarin.forms

Currently i working on Creating WCF service in order to communicate xamarin forms (Android) with sqlserver. For that i have tried some examples from the following link https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/web-services/consuming/wcf/ but it was not working also it throws error(SystemError).

My goal : i have to retrieve data from sqlserver using WCF service . Kindly provide ideas to solve this issues.

Thanks.
krupa

Comment: Are you asking for assistance with your current code, or asking for help writing something new?

Comment: How are we supposed to help you if you don't show us what you're doing?  You haven't provided any amount of detail that would allow us to help you.  Please post the releant portions of your code, the exact error message you are getting, and the line of code that is throwing the error.

Answer (score 0):

i think you want to create web-service, you can learn how to make wcf [from here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386386.aspx)

- webservices is same like an other client-server architecture where you send request to server and get response.
- now make one hello world webservices base on above example

  - Request - in request you have to send data you can use xml or json
  - in method of webservice you have to process your data [calculate/store in DB/etc]
  - in response you send response data back

*to test a webservice use postman extension in chrome browser